# Orthogonal sequences under A Hillbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I know that for two vectors $u,v\in H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space the definition for orthogonality is $\langle u,v \rangle =0$. is thaat also corret for sequences?

What is the definition for orthogonal sequences under a Hilbert space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, $(x_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is called an *orthogonal sequence* if $\langle x_j, x_k \rangle = 0$ whenever $j \neq k$.

Comment: That was all to easy.  ;-)